# css div + background-image

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know what I am doing wrong regarding the use of background-image property, I want the picture to always be displayed in its full-size adjusted perfectly to its parenting div (no matter what kind of resolution it'd be displayed on), here's what I've got to so far, I am completely aware that the problem isn't that complex but I just cannot get through it! Thanks for any help.

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://kingofwallpapers.com/picture/picture-008.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're close. You just have to set background-size to contain. `contain` scales the background image to parent dimensions (without stretching, i.e. the smallest, either width or height.)

`background-repeat` is just for not repeating the background over and over again

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://kingofwallpapers.com/picture/picture-008.jpg);
    background-size: contain;
    /* background-size: 100% 100%; <- stretch fit to parent */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation for your answer?

Comment: and what if I wanted the picture to have 100% width while preserving its original height? thanks for the answer btw.

Comment: Just to add, the default size for a background image is its actual size

Comment: @KarlFriedrich isn't that what you're getting in `cover` mode

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
background-size: cover;
```

you should use:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

So I Think this code could help:

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}

header {
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url(http://kingofwallpapers.com/picture/picture-008.jpg);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
</header>
```